# "start /b" seems to cause "taskkill" to fail in batch scripts

Tags: windows, batch-file, taskkill

For reasons that have yet to be determined, the **/b** switch in **start /b** causes **taskkill** to fail to find the first instance:

```
INFO: No tasks running with the specified criteria
```

This is a simple example of the code in question (has **/b** and does not work). Copy the code and paste in notepad and save as batch file. It will restart with the cmd switch "/k", then it will create a second instance, then the second instance will attempt to end the first. If needed, original script can be found [here](http://code.google.com/p/quick-net-fix/source/browse/nwcr_simple.cmd?r=3e1eebd7e1449f73d9b9df1725ed96ff676504dd).

```
@prompt :
%zero%@set zero=::&start /b "" "cmd" /k "%~dpnx0"&goto :eof

%first%@TITLE First Instance
%first%@set first=::&start "" cmd /C "%~dpnx0"&goto :waiting

taskkill /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq First Instance"
taskkill /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Administrator:  First Instance"

:waiting
pause>nul
```

Here is the same example without the **/b** switch. That is the only difference between the two. It works as it should:

```
@prompt :
%zero%@set zero=::&start "" "cmd" /k "%~dpnx0"&goto :eof

%first%@TITLE First Instance
%first%@set first=::&start "" cmd /C "%~dpnx0"&goto :waiting

taskkill /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq First Instance"
taskkill /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Administrator:  First Instance"

:waiting
pause>nul
```

To reiterate my question: how can one get taskkill to work with the **/b** switch of start? An explanation of why it doesn't work as it is would be nice as well.

Comment: A proof of concept using notepad and simple commands would be useful.

Comment: The examples have been significantly simplified. Hope this helps

Comment: edited the question: removed explanation of why the code might be used and slightly reworded the question.

Comment: Er, the first has `exit /b` whereas the second has `exit` in addition to the `start [/b]`

Comment: No more exit commands. problem has not changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
@prompt :
%zero%@set zero=::&start "Zeroth instance" "cmd" /k "%~dpnx0"&pause&goto :eof
ECHO Maybe CHANGE TITLE...
pause
%first%@TITLE First Instance
%first%@set first=::&start "Second instance" cmd /C "%~dpnx0"&goto :waiting
ECHO got here-------------
pause
taskkill /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq First Instance"
taskkill /F /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Administrator:  First Instance"

:waiting
ECHO waiting...
PAUSE
exit
GOTO :EOF
```

Minor changes with lots of echoes and pauses...

If you run an additional session using `tasklist /v|find /i "cmd"` you'll find that with the above code, the window title "Zeroth instance" will be changed to "First instance" when the appropriate `pause` receives a response. Allowing 'Second instance`to reach the`taskkill`s will close the`Zeroth/First` window and if either new window reaches the exit statement, that instance is terminated. All fine and good and as expected. Using the additional session, you can see the various phases entered.

If you reintroduce the `/b` switch, then *THAT* instance no longer has its own window, and hence the window that it hasn't got can't have a title. You can see this using the additional session. Now - getting that particular session to terminate is a bit of a game.... not sure `start /b` plays nicely with an interactive batch...

Comment: Interesting that despite the script's ability to change the current console window title, that title does not actually belong to it. Is there any way to set the TITLE property of the parent instance from the child instance?